# bootstrap angular datepicker change template

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

i try to change the layout of my datepicker. i am using `angular-ui` bootstrap for the `datepicker`

i use this tag 
`<input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="model" is-open="opened" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />`

can anyone give me an example ?

my layout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9tkp.jpg
layout i want:
https://raw.github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/screenshots/day.png

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the Angular-Strap Project which tries to achieve the same functionality.

Just look at these [demos](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers). Isn't that pretty near to the layout you want?

Comment: thats what i need, but i have to do it with bootstrap ui i also tried it with angular strap but i got the same result (also the first datepicker) if you click on the plunker example you will also see the first layout

Comment: Oh, I see. Must have changed their templates. But in strap you can define your own templates and add them as url to your options. Maybe you should check if this is possible in bootstrap-ui too by now. Sadly these demo pages always have a lag to the actual versions:-\

Answer (score 0):

The 1.0 release of https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker allows you to override the templates

Answer (score -2):

I just built a template for **AngularStrap DatePicker** integrated with Bootstrap Datepicker by [eternicode](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker). I think the output of eternicode datepicker is completely looks like what you need.

here is my template code :

```
'<div class="datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top" ng-class="\'datepicker-mode-\' + $mode"><div class="datepicker-days" style="display:block;"><table class=" table-condensed" style="width: 100%"><thead><tr><th class="prev" style="visibility: visible;" ng-click="$selectPane(-1)"><i class="{{$iconLeft}}"></i></th><th colspan="{{ rows[0].length - 2 }}" class=" datepicker-switch" ng-click="$toggleMode()" ng-bind="title"></th><th class="next" style="visibility: visible;" ng-click="$selectPane(+1)"><i class="{{$iconRight}}"></i></th></tr><tr ng-show="showLabels" ng-bind-html="labels"></tr></thead><tbody><tr ng-repeat="(i, row) in rows"><td class="day" ng-repeat="(j, el) in row" ng-class="{\'btn-primary\': el.selected, \'btn-info btn-today\': el.isToday && !el.selected, \'text-muted\': el.muted, \' old \':el.muted}" ng-click="$select(el.date)" ng-disabled="el.disabled" ng-bind="el.label"></td></tr></tbody></table></div></div>'
```

You can replace this line with built-in template in ***angular-strap.tpl.js***  or put it in a new .html file in default template path for AngularStrap datepicker in ***datepicker/datepicker.tpl.html***. 
Finally you should add the [css or less](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/blob/master/less/datepicker3.less) version of eternicode datepicker to your page.

I hope this may help you.